# Necessity of using emitter follower as the first stage

Tags: operational-amplifier, emitter-follower

What's the actual use of the emitter follower stage (Q1&Q2) in the following op-amp circuit? The only reason I see is to increase the input impedance. But even that I don't see it necessary because the source impedance is only 50 ohms and a common collector would be superfluous in this case. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: To satisfy the design requirements. Since we don't know what those are... a guess would be that it has to do with HF performance, from Rs=50 ohms. But it probably isn't to isolate the input from Miller effect in Q3 since Q5 looks suspiciously like it MIGHT be a cascode load...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an input stage of an opamp or comparator. The source impedance will contain also all the external circuits between the Vin or Vip input and the actual voltage source of the circuit which feeds the input signals. There can be for ex. a megaohm resistor as the last part of the  signal feeding circuit. The "superfluous" emitter follower stage can be very useful in that case.

Of course we do not know the design goals of the shown circuit, so we cannot be sure if that "megaohm external impedance" ever occurs. If not, then the emitter follower stages before the differential amp can well be superfluous.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Only if the source resistance is considerably high can we think of this stage. For a moment I thought the source impedance is only 50 ohms, and so probably no extra mega ohms in there. That made me really foolish. Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

The role of the additional emitter followers Q1-Q2 is to enormously decrease the input bias currents. Why?

The input differential pair Q3-Q4 is biased (supplied by an initial input signal) by the current source I0. It tries to inject its current into the emitters but it cannot do it directly. First, base currents have to flow through the base-emitter junctions so that the transistors adjust its base-emutter voltages to pass the emitter current.

The paths of these currents are closed through external resistors, which may be of high resistance and voltage drops appear across them. In order to keep them to minimum, the base currents must be minimal.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: The example circuit shows bipolar supply voltages. In such a case, we normally design such a circuit so that there is no need for base biasing resistors (Vbase=0). Hence, we do not need "high resistance" parts for closing the base current path. I rather think, it is the only task of the additional stage at the inputs to provide a larger input resistance of the diff. amplifier. Without these stages, the input resistance for (unsymm.) diff.signals is only 2hie (some kOhms).

Comment: @LvW, "Larger input resistance" and "smaller bias currents" are almost equal. Regarding the "need for base biasing resistors"... there is a need of "something" to ensure a path for the input bias currents. Usually, this is the (galvanic) input source but when it is not galvanic (conductive), we close the current path by such resistors. They have to have high enough resistance not to shunt significantly the input source... and low enough resistance because of the undesired voltage drops across them.